# Javascript object wrong value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React app, where i have this function being called after a click:

```js
dispatch( {type: 'ADD_TO_CART', payload: { cartProduct: {...props, quantity: 1} }})
```

The types are:

```js
interface ICartProduct extends IProduct { 
    quantity: number
}

interface ICartItem { 
    product: ICartProduct
}

export interface IProduct {
    id: number
    category: string
    description: string
    name: string
    brand: string
    price: number
    linkImg: string
}

export interface IState { 
    isCheckoutResume: boolean
    isAddress: boolean
    isPayment: boolean
    isSuccess: boolean
    isHomePage: boolean
    cart: Array<ICartProduct>
    products: Array<IProduct>
}
```

Inside the reducer function, i have this:

```js
export const reducer = (state: IState, action: IAction): IState => { 

    switch (action.type){ 

        //other features

        case ('ADD_TO_CART'):
            if(action?.payload?.cartProduct) { 

                console.log(action.payload.cartProduct.quantity) // logs always 1, which is expected 
                console.log(action.payload.cartProduct) // logs always an objects having in the quantity property the double + 2 of the value that is already in the cart for that product, so in the second click for the same product it gives 4 (1*2 + 2), in the third click it is 10 (4*2 + 2)
```

I can't figure out what is happening, should not these lines logs the same value for **quantity** since it is the same javascript object?

This is not related to console logging only since the application state for cart is also carrying this behavior.

Thank you.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: This is due to lazy loading the object in the console. The quantity changed between the `console.log()` and you clicking the drop-down arrow in the debugger. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/12914833. You can use `console.log(action.payload.cartProduct.toString())` to avoid lazy loading.